# Efficient Iteration Through Tree-Like System

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got a tree-like system which is created by one object containing a list of references to another type of object which contains a list of references to another... etc.

Thus giving me a tree of objects, all of differing types.

Now, what I am doing right now is simply using 'for each' loops to grab each element under its parent all the way until I get to the objects that I want. (These objects contain a string that I need access too. If this string matches what I'm looking for, then I set a flag. There could be multiple matches, but I only need to confirm one.)

This raises another point as to what should happen once I set that flag, seeing as I don't need to continue any further. This is because if the match is found on one string, then I can assume I can to continue with the rest of my program. Therefore, this makes the rest of the iterations on the tree pointless.

I am working in C++ MFC, and consequently I am searching for a CString if that matters.

The layers of containers holding "children" objects start as a Vector of parent objects, followed by a List of children objects followed by a List of children objects.

Making a branch of the tree look like:

`Initial Vector: { 1object1, 1object2, 1object3, ..., 1objectN }`

```
object1 List: { 2object1, 2object2, 2object3, ...,2objectN }

2object1 List: { 3object1, ... 3objectN }

if (3object1.name() == "match")
{
    flag = TRUE;
    break?
}
```

To keep the question generic, I'm not too picky on the implementation used even though I'm using vectors and lists.

My actual code looks something like this:

```
bool flag = FALSE;
    for each (1Object 1object in m_1Objects)
        for each (2Object 2object in 1object.Get2Objects())
            for each (3Object 3object in 2object.Get3Objects())
                if (3object.GetName() == "match") flag = TRUE;
```

As you can tell this could take forever to run once the system gets too big. Especially since I'm not sure how to break out of it once the flag is set.

What would be a more efficient and cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: I would use an extra structure, maybe a CMap object keyed by name, that stores lists of 3Object instances.  This should scale well. The problem is you need logic to keep both your tree structure and the CMap instance in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of ways to handle it.

The easiest - and ''hackiest'' way is to throw an exception once the item is found and catch it outside of the loop. Not neat, not nice, but it will work. And you can still use `std::for_each`. To illustrate (not that I approve of this solution):

```
bool flag = FALSE;                                                                                                                                                  
try {
    for each (1Object 1object in m_1Objects)
        for each (2Object 2object in 1object.Get2Objects())
            for each (3Object 3object in 2object.Get3Objects())
                if (3object.GetName() == "match") throw true;
} catch (bool e) {
    flag = TRUE;
}
```

Another way is to use `std::find_if` instead of `std::for_each`, and on each level checking whether the iterator returned by `find_if` is last or not. (Last would indicate item not found).

But what I think is the easiest way would be to implement the foreach iteration as simple for loops with the conditional statement including the flag, e.g. this code

```
bool flag = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !flag; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    if (5 == i)
        flag = true;
}
```

will output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Does that help your question?

Comment: If you do not approve of your own solution, what do you recommend?

Comment: I don't understand your comment... Anyways, of the three proposed solutions, I'd go with the third one if writing simple one-off code and with the second one if I were to write maintainable code for the future.

Comment: Okay, you said, "To illustrate (not that I approve of this solution)" which confused me since I asked for a "more efficient and cleaner way" to perform my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate this nested search loop into a const method that returns true/false.  Then when you find the item, simply "return true;"